# Ordering with relation column sum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Questions hasMany Answers. Answers hasMany Comments and Votes. Comments hasMany votes.

I need to order the answer by the votes. The answer table do not have votes column. But, the answer hasMany relation with votes. The votes table has a vote column, and the sum of the vote column gives the total votes. Currently, by default the answers are ordered by id.

```
$questions = Question::with('users', 'answers', 'answers.comments.votes', 'answers.votes')->get();              
foreach($questions as $question)
{
   print_r($question->question);       
   foreach($question->answers as $answer)
   {
        print_r($answer->answer);      
        $votes = $answer->votes->sum('vote');
        print_r($votes);                
    } 
}
```

An answer has many votes and many comments. Comments have many votes. So, a polymorphic relation.

```
votes table.
id user_id  vote  votable_id  votable_type
1     4       4     1           App\Answer
2     5       3     1           App\Answer
......
```

Here the votes of answer id 1 is 7. How do I order the answer with greatest votes?

Comment: Could You provide the code for the relation? I guess the work can be done there using JOIN statement and ORDER BY

Comment: @ad4s yes.edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Provide the relations so it would be easy to get the solution. From my understanding, if you want to order inside the nested relation by a column, you can try this code:

```
$questions = Question::with(['users','answers' => function ($query)
                {   
                        $query->orderBy('column','Desc')
                              ->with('comments.votes')   
                              ->with('votes');   
                }])->get();
```

Comment: but i donot have votes column in answers table. votes are the sum of 'vote' column in votes table.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve Answer model instances, ordered by the sum of votes try this (untested) snippet

```
Answer::join('votes', function($join)
    {
        $join->on('votes.votable_id', '=', 'answer.id');
        $join->where('votes.votable_type', '=', 'answer');
    })
    ->groupBy('answer.id')
    ->orderByRaw('sum(votes.vote)')
    ->limit(10)
    ->get();
```

In the future it might be a trick to count votes every time for many answers. Keeping a sum of votes in answer table comes to mind.